# Open file with absolute or relative path

Tags: angular

Upon selecting an XML file, the client has to read it.
The XML file contains a path (can be relative) to another XML file. 
I tried to read and got:

> Not allowed to load local resource: file:///D:/Temp/dwell.xml

How can bypass this security issue?

```
window.open('file:///D:/Temp/dwell.xml');
```

Comment: you cannot read file:/// without disabling web security in chrome options, this is a safety measure by browsers so that sites dont steal data from your local filesystem

Comment: Run this through a Webserver and make it http accessible

Comment: Hi Marged. Thank you very much ! It seems this is the most elegant solution.